# Transfer data from php as json, then store it in global object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following code:

**PHP code:**

```
$data = array();
$data[0]['name'] = "Kj";
$data[0]['age'] = 30;
$data[0]['country'] = "Italy";

$data[1]['name'] = "Dn";
$data[1]['age'] = 18;
$data[1]['country'] = "USA";

$data[2]['name'] = "Jo";
$data[2]['age'] = 22;
$data[2]['country'] = "Switzerland";

$data[3]['name'] = "Ro";
$data[3]['age'] = 34;
$data[3]['country'] = "UAE";

$data[4]['name'] = "Lc";
$data[4]['age'] = 13;
$data[4]['country'] = "UK";

echo json_encode($data);
```

**Javascript code:**

```
var jsonData = {};
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('page.php', function (data) {
        jsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    });
});

for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    $('ul').append("<li>" + jsonData[i].name + "</li>");
}
```

The problem is when put the for loop inside the `$.get callback` works fine like as the following.

```
$.get('page.php', function (data) {
    jsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        $('ul').append("<li>" + jsonData[i].name + "</li>");
    }
});
```

But when put the for loop outside the `$.get callback` does not print out anything, but the data has been received successfully, but without print it.

Now, how can store the data that has been received in global variable to print it in anywhere ?

Comment: because your for loop "which is outside" gets executed before the json is received. You will have to keep the for loop inside $.get() , or call a function from $.get() and in that function keep that for loop

Comment: Just suggestion: use `$.getJSON()` instead `.get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your approach when you work with asynchronous operations (AJAX, timeouts). Something like this:

```
function GetData(callback) {
    $.get('page.php', function (data) {
        callback(jQuery.parseJSON(data));
    });
}

GetData(function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('ul').append("<li>" + data[i].name + "</li>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain how would this work with the async nature of ajax?

Comment: Sorry.I changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code already stores data in a global variable correctly.
Type `jsonData` into F12-javascript console and you will see it.

The question is rather about the control flow, what is the other event that will trigger usage of `jsonData`?